# How to get the passed variable which then rewritted from .htaccess in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my php code i have passed the variables in url as slug like :

```
https://localhost/subject/index.php?sub=web-technology
```

Here `sub` is the variable name where web-technology is passes as slug from the database, and then the url is rewritten by `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subject/index/sub/(.*) /subject/index.php?sub=$1
RewriteRule ^subject/index/sub/(.*)/ /subject/index.php?sub=$1
```

From there the url I got is

```
https://localhost.com/subject/index/sub/web-technology/
```

or

```
https://localhost/subject/index/sub/[Any_Value]/
```

The php code I have in my web is

```
$subject =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['sub']);
```

on where I want the slug value in GET variable and match it in database to get the respective data. I cannot get the variable so I cannot retrieve the information from my database.

Can anyone help me with it or can give different ways on how I can make it work properly?

Comment: To be clear, your rewrite rule will rewrite `.../subject/index/sub/web-technology/` in the browser *to* `.../subject/index.php?sub=web-technology` (not the opposite, which is how your text seems to describe it).  The rewrite is internal, so the URL in the browser does not change.  And in `/subject/index.php`, `$_GET['sub']` should work.  Do you have other rewrite rules in your `.htaccess`?  Try `print_r($_SERVER);` in `/subject/index.php`?  BTW you do not need `RewriteEngine On` 2x.

Comment: `https://localhost/subject/index.php?sub=web-technology ` In this url the get variable gets the data but after .htaccess the url that works is  `https://localhost.com/subject/index/sub/web-technology/` in this url the same code doesnot work it doesnot find any value `web-technology` so that i cannot match it with database slug

Answer (score 1):

Your rules are in the wrong order. Unless `/subject/index/sub/` maps to a physical directory then your first rule (that appends the `.php` extension) will attempt to rewrite the request first and prevent the later rules from being processed.

The second rule will also take priority over the third rule, capturing the trailing slash, so the third rule is never processed.

Since you are rewriting extensionless URLs, you need to make sure that MultiViews is also disabled, otherwise this will take priority and the URL parameters will not be passed to your script.

Try your rules like this instead:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite to "/subject/index.php?sub=<string>"
RewriteRule ^subject/index/sub/([^/]+)/?$ /subject/index.php?sub=$1 [L]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, once you've "turned it on", it stays on.

---

**UPDATE:**

> `https://localhost/subject/content.php?sub=digital-logic&content=this-is-content/` i want that url to `https://localhost/subject/content/sub/digital-logic&content/this-is-content/` or any that is possible and i need those both slug for fetching data from different database tables

The same principle applies as above, you just need to be specific in which parts of the URL-path you need to capture in order to create backreferences (ie. `$1` and `$2`) that can be used in the *substitution* string.

Add the following as the first rule, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
# Internally rewrite to "/subject/index.php?sub=<string>"
RewriteRule ^subject/content/sub/([^/&]+)&content/(.+) /subject/content.php?sub=$1&content=$2 [L]
```

This uses two backreferences, whereas the example above uses just one.

Comment: Yes that works i think .Thanks for the help .will contact if needed

Comment: @NarayanDhakal You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" (grey/green checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to help other readers and remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: ``` https://localhost/subject/content.php?sub=digital-logic&content=this-is-content/  ```  i want that url to `https://localhost/subject/content/sub/digital-logic&content/this-is-content/` or any that is possible and i need those both slug for fetching data from different database tables what can be the solution .and i want to learn about .htaccess .recommend me some best resources and videos that help me with it

Comment: @sanzgrapher I've updated my answer covering that additional example.

Comment: @sanzgrapher If this answers your question then please mark it as accepted (grey/green checkmark below the voting arrows on the left of the answer) to help other readers and remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find help. Thanks, much appreciated :)

Comment: @sanzgrapher "i want to learn about .htaccess" - Learning about `.htaccess` is learning about Apache configuration. However, what we are dealing with here is specifically mod_rewrite. For mod_rewrite my go to reference is the official Apache docs and is a good place to start IMO: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html